# Execute UiAutomator commands within appium script

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator, appium-android

I was wonder if there a way to execute UiAutomator commands straight from appium test ?

The only API I do see is `"findElementByAndroidUIAutomator"` which expect to get a return value from uiutomator (UiScrollable / UiObject) in order to look after it.

In my flow I trying to execute a `UiScrollable().flingBackward()` command which returns boolean value ...

Is there a way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to run native Uiautomator code except the one you mentioned: `findElementByAndroidUIAutomator`

So you either try it with e.g. scrollIntoView and criteria to find element at place to stop scroling, or take a look at TouchActons Appium client class.

Comment: The idea is not just to perform a scroll , but to execute some uiautomator code which doesn't return Object

Comment: I got your point, but you still can try to sent whatever you want as argument, just handle the exception. The thing is: Appium do not expose methods to run adb, Uiautomator, etc. per design

Comment: The exception is not on the client side, but on the usually on the server, in the specific case, the exception is on the uiautomator netty server which is running within the device

Answer (score 0):

Though not Appium, this is a [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/) generated script that does exactly what you are looking for, invoking `flingBackward()` on a `UIScrollable` object, Launcher workspace in this case

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2018  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2018-04-02 by CulebraTester 
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


import unittest
try:
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass

import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require('androidviewclient>=12.4.0')
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, CulebraTestCase
from com.dtmilano.android.uiautomator.uiautomatorhelper import UiAutomatorHelper, UiScrollable, UiObject, UiObject2

TAG = 'CULEBRA'


class CulebraTests(CulebraTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
        cls.kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': True, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
        cls.options = {'start-activity': None, 'concertina': False, 'device-art': None, 'use-jar': False, 'multi-device': False, 'unit-test-class': True, 'save-screenshot': None, 'use-dictionary': False, 'glare': False, 'dictionary-keys-from': 'id', 'scale': 1, 'find-views-with-content-description': True, 'window': -1, 'orientation-locked': None, 'save-view-screenshots': None, 'find-views-by-id': True, 'log-actions': False, 'use-regexps': False, 'null-back-end': False, 'auto-regexps': None, 'do-not-verify-screen-dump': True, 'verbose-comments': False, 'gui': False, 'find-views-with-text': True, 'prepend-to-sys-path': False, 'install-apk': None, 'drop-shadow': False, 'output': None, 'unit-test-method': None, 'interactive': False}
        cls.sleep = 5

    def setUp(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(CulebraTests, self).tearDown()

    def preconditions(self):
        if not super(CulebraTests, self).preconditions():
            return False
        return True

    def testSomething(self):
        if not self.preconditions():
            self.fail('Preconditions failed')

        _s = CulebraTests.sleep
        _v = CulebraTests.verbose

        UiScrollable(self.vc.uiAutomatorHelper, uiSelector='clazz@com.android.launcher3.Workspace,res@com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher:id/workspace,index@0,parentIndex@0,package@com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher').flingBackward()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CulebraTests.main()
```